# criteria query left outer join is not returning proper value

Tags: java, jpa, join, predicate, criteria-api

I have 2 tables that have a relationship of many to many. 1 table is user, and the second table is group. This means 1 user can have many group. And 1 group can have many user. This is the content of my table:

```
      Table User                              Table Group
+------------------------------+      +-----------------------------+
| Name   | Age |  Group        |      | Name     | User             |
+------------------------------+      +-----------------------------+
|Fikrie  | 21  |  Unix         |      | Unix     | Fikrie, Fikrie1  |
|Fikrie1 | 22  |  Windows      |      | Windows  | Fikrie1,Fikrie2  |
|Fikrie2 | 23  |  Unix,Windows |      | HP-UX    |                  |
|Lucy    | 21  |               |      +-----------------------------+
|Lucy1   | 22  |               |
+------------------------------+
```

Whenever I try to query, I only manage to get the user that have group. For may case, I only manage to get all the Fikries. Why is my query missing Lucys? This is my code:

```
public List<User> retrieveAll(String nameFilter, String groupFilter, int start, int length) {

    logger.info("nameFilter = [" + nameFilter + "]");
    logger.info("groupFilter = [" + groupFilter + "]");
    logger.info("start is = [" + start + "]");
    logger.info("length is = [" + length + "]");

    ServiceUtil.requireAdmin();
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<User> q = cb.createQuery(User.class);
    Root<User> c = q.from(User.class);
    Join<User, UserGroup> usrGrp = c.join(
            User_.userGroups, JoinType.LEFT);

    q.select(c);

    Predicate namePredicate = cb.like(c.get(User_.name), "%"
            + nameFilter.toLowerCase() + "%");        
    Predicate groupPredicate = cb.like(usrGrp.get(UserGroup_.name),
            "%" + groupFilter.toLowerCase() + "%");        
    Predicate andPredicate = cb.and(namePredicate, groupPredicate);
    q.where(andPredicate);

    List<User> results = em.createQuery(q).setFirstResult(start)
            .setMaxResults(length).getResultList();
    int i = 0;
    for (User usr : results) {
        logger.info("Name=" + usr.getName());
        for (UsrGroup usrgroup2 : usr.getUserGroups()) {
            logger.info("usrgroups = [" + usrgroup2.getName() + "]");
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

This is the log after running the query:

```
nameFilter = []
groupFilter = []
start is = [0]
length is = [5]
Name=Fikrie
usrgroups = [Unix]
Name=Fikrie1
usrgroups= [Windows]
Name=Fikrie2
usrgroups= [Unix]
usrgroups= [Windows]
```

From [this](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Criteria#JoinType) documentation, it says to use Left type of join to apply a left outer join. Why is it still missing the other 2 user that does not have any group?From my understanding by referring [here](http://www.akadia.com/services/sqlsrv_join_tables.html), the left outer join should do the trick.

What I tried:

Remove the `groupPredicate`, just do a filtering by name. Then I get all the user.

log result:

```
nameFilter = []
groupFilter = []
start is = [0]
length is = [5]
Name=Fikrie
usrgroups = [Unix]
Name=Fikrie1
usrgroups= [Windows]
Name=Fikrie2
usrgroups= [Unix]
usrgroups= [Windows]
Name=Lucy
Name=Lucy1
```

From my understanding, if I dont query by group, it will return all. But if I add a Predicate to query by group, then it will filter out the user including those that have null group. Is that the default behaviour for `LEFT` type of join? I just want to filter out user that have group. For user that dont have, I dont want to filter. Is it possible to do so in criteriabuilder?

**UPDATE:**

I was thinking maybe its not because of the outer join but because of the query itself. To confirm this, I add another column in the Table User to become like this:

```
     Table User                              
+-------------------------------------------+      
| Name   | Age |  Group        | Skill      |
+-------------------------------------------+     
|Fikrie  | 21  |  Unix         |  <NULL>    |
|Fikrie1 | 22  |  Windows      |  <NULL>    |
|Fikrie2 | 23  |  Unix,Windows |  <NULL>    |    
|Lucy    | 21  |               |  killer    |
|Lucy1   | 22  |               |  <NULL>    |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

Then I change the query to become like this:

```
    q.select(c);

    Predicate namePredicate = cb.like(c.get(User_.name), "%"
            + nameFilter.toLowerCase() + "%");        
    Predicate skillPredicate = cb.like(c.get(User_.skill),
            "%" + groupFilter.toLowerCase() + "%");        
    Predicate andPredicate = cb.and(namePredicate, skillPredicate);
    q.where(andPredicate);

    List<User> results = em.createQuery(q).setFirstResult(start)
            .setMaxResults(length).getResultList();
    int i = 0;
    for (User usr : results) {
        logger.info("Name=[" + usr.getName() + "], skill=" + usr.getSkill() + "]");

    }
    return results;
```

This is the log for the new test:

```
nameFilter = []
groupFilter = []
start is = [0]
length is = [5]

Name=[Lucy], skill=[killer]
```

I'm not 100% sure but I think my query is having a problem when handling a NULL value.

Comment: Why are you still filtering using name and group even though they are empty strings? I suggest that you set conditions and add only the appropriate Predicates when your filters are not empty.

Comment: Because I'm working on adding a filter enhancement. If the filter is empty,it should display all my data. That is why I'm passing an empty filter.I can do the condition. But what happen if I pass the filter for group? The problem is there cause the other 2 users does not have any data. Does passing an empty filter got anything to do with quering a table that have null? Eg. Lucy usrGroup is null.

Comment: so at no point have you actually looked at the SQL generated?

Comment: by `SQL generated`, do you mean like `SELECT * from User where ......`